# Unable to start kafka Broker service in cluster cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-cloudformation

We are creating KAFKA cluster open source kafka this version:

https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/1.0.0/kafka_2.11-1.0.0.tgz

While creating a 6 node kafka cluster with both broker and zookeeper on same node the service start for broker does not happen as per userdata commands.

$KAFKA_INSTALL_DIR/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_INSTALL_DIR/config/server.properties

I have also introduced sleep with 10m after zookeeper service start. So that sync of zookeeper service can be done.

Comment: Are there any errors in logs?

Comment: How  many ZooKeeper Nodes and Kafka nodes do you have ?

Comment: 6 nodes are present in cluster. both zookeeper and broker services are running on each node created as part of cloudformation.

Comment: I have noticed this error in server.log file : 
[2019-01-18 07:33:35,596] ERROR Unexpected exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
@wardziniak

Comment: @vamsikrishna, how you can see there is some connection issue. Could you attach Kafka and zookeeper configuration file, with information about machines where zookeeper and kafka is deployed (ip addresses)